# Creating a login screen with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, azure, swiftui

I want to make a login screen for my app where the UI is done in SwiftUI.

I'm using BD B2C with Azure.

I've taken one of the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-native-appauth) codes (which is written with UIKit) and implemented it into SwiftUI, but I want users to sign in on the app itself, not on a webpage.

I've now created a Sign in using resource owner password credentials (ROPC) user flow.

However, after reading though the docs, I don't understand how I can use my own UI for this without opening a webpage.

I've been stuck on this for hours and I'll reply quickly to any questions

Thinking about moving back to AWS. However, I'll have to live with Amazon snooping on all my storage.

Comment: You'll want something like a RESTful API. What service do you want to use for your backend exactly, it's not that clear in your question?

Comment: I recommend firebase for authentication.

Comment: @Nathan I'm trying to use Azure BD B2C to provide the backend for authentication, then submit the details from a SwiftUI form. I remember making something similar in firebase and it was much simpler. I could potentially just use AWS/Firebase for auth, then Azure for everything else